# Image appears off screen android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to move an image around the screen but sometimes the image either appears half off  the screen or completely off. 
My code looks like:

```
width = image.getWidth();
height = image.getHeight();
main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
screenWidth = main.getWidth();
screenHeight = main.getHeight();
xCalc = screenWidth - width;
yCalc = screenHeight - height;
imageParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
Random rand = new Random();

xValue = (int) (rand.nextFloat() * xCalc);
yValue = (int) (rand.nextFloat() * yCalc);
imageParams.setMargins(xValue, yValue, 0, 0);
image.setLayoutParams(dotParams);
```

Comment: Why not just use a XML layout to do this?

Comment: Because I want the image it change location on a button press